# Search a generated format in Django Database

Tags: python, django

In my django app I am creating Barcodes with a combination of `str` and `id` of model and `id` of product.
The barcode is generated but the problem that I am encountering is when I scan the barcode I want to show the  information of the product scanned.

I'll be able to understand the problem with code in a better way

Models.py

```
class GrnItems(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)



class Grn(models.Model):
    
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(GrnItems)
```

Views.py

```
def PrintGRNsv1(request, pk):
    

    grn = Grn.objects.filter(pk=pk)[0]
    grn_prod = grn.items.all()
    print("grn prod", grn_prod)

    items = []

    for i in grn_prod:
        for j in range(i.item_quantity):

            items.append({'bar': "YNT9299" + str(pk) +
                                 str(i.item.pk) + str(j + 1)} )
```

Now let's suppose I generated a Barcode `YNT92991231`, Now I have no idea how to get the `i.item.pk` from this code

How can I do this ?

P.s.
Okay the cherry on top is that I have created the Barcodes for a large number of products and they are already placed on them, so can't really change the barcode format at this point

Comment: Probably you should use some delimiter.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Okay the cherry on top is that I have created the Barcodes for a large number of products and they are already placed on them

Comment: The answer is that you can't do this - not without delimiters as has been pointed out. The different `pk` values and that final counter (`j + 1`) will bleed together and you won't know where one ends and the next starts. Fixed width with limited length pks would also have worked, but you don't have that either.

Comment: @urbanespaceman So should I resign now or wait till they find it ?

Comment: Haha. Can't answer that one I'm afraid. But this is a biggie, so probably best to ´fess up ... Depending on how many have been issued and what `pk` ranges you already have - and if you have the possibility to halt production of more for a while - there _may_ be a way out ... it's entirely dependant on existing data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now when we can't change anything. Generate all the barcodes for you `GRN`. Save them in files or in DB. Whenever there is a query that matches those just find them from there. If there is any conflict (when 2 or more product has the same barcode) Django USER can be one way to resolve the conflict.

For new barcodes change the generator function. Use delimiter or fixed-width characters (for pk).

ex: `YNT9299GGGGGPPPPPCCCCC` where G => GRN pk, P => Product pk, C => Count. Or with delimiters `YNT9299G1P23C2`.

Yep, the solution is not a foolproof solution is just a workaround for the mess created.